# jquery: how to get a row of json data from the json data list by id, etc?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-1.9

I have a json data like this below, how can I select the row of data by its **id** or by its **email**, etc?

```
[ 
Object { id="40", full_name="lau", email="kok@com", more...},  
Object { id="39", full_name="Kok", email="lau@lauthiamkok.net", more...},  
Object { id="5", full_name="Alice", email="alice@umbrellacorp.com", more...},  
4 more... 
]
```

if I do this,

```
console.log(app.contacts[0]);
```

I always get the first row only.

Can I use `jquery.get()` to get a row from the list, something like this below?

```
console.log(app.contacts.get({id:5}));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to iterate and check the id or email property in the loop

```
var obj;

for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if ( arr[i].id == '40' ) {
        obj = arr[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/V4UxX/)

Also, the posted array / objects are not valid