# JSON-how to get the single content from a json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

hi i retrieve data as a JSON string like

```
var jsonPretty = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);

{
    "GetPageInfoResult": [{
        "main": {
            "sub": [],
            "tittle": "hllo",
            "startvalue": "21",
            "stopvalue": "45",
            "status": "",
            "accumalated": "",
            "comment": ""
        }
    }]
}
```

how can i get my my column content as:

`$("tr[data-id=1] > td:nth-child(1)").text(hllo)`.

`$("tr[data-id=1] > td:nth-child(2)").text(21)`

`$("tr[data-id=1] > td:nth-child(3)").text(45)`

Comment: `data[0].main["start value"]` will fetch you `21`

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xLofv5oL/1)

Comment: This might helps you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20813223/jquery-how-to-get-a-row-of-json-data-from-the-json-data-list-by-id-etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/d5qe70bw/

```
var mr_cools_data = [{
    "main": {
        "sub": [],
        "tittle": "water",
        "start value": "21",
        "stop value": "45",
        "status": "",
        "accumulated": "",
        "comment": ""
    }
}]

$("tr[data-id=1] > td:nth-child(1)").text(mr_cools_data[0].main['tittle'])

$("tr[data-id=1] > td:nth-child(2)").text(mr_cools_data[0].main['start value'])

$("tr[data-id=1] > td:nth-child(3)").text(mr_cools_data[0].main['stop value'])
```

Also, consider removing the [] from the json, that wraps the 'main' object in an array which seems useless with this data. Also, naming the attributes without whitespace is recommended(change `start value` to `start_value`)

Comment: but there is an error shown " can not read properly 'tittle'" of undefined

Comment: Check out the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d5qe70bw/. You have to assign your json to the mr_cools_data.

Comment: actually my data is getting in a function like   success: function (data) {
                debugger;
 $("tr[data-id=1] > td:nth-child(1)").text(data[0].main['tittle'])
}

Comment: could you `console.log(data)` in the function and post the result?

Comment: can you please check my question now i edit it

Comment: Then I guess you have to do `jsonPretty.GetPageInfoResult[0].main.tittle `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122713/discussion-between-mr-cool-and-martin-gottweis).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var jsonPretty  = [{
    "main": {
        "sub": [],
         "tittle": "hllo",
            "startvalue": "",
            "stopvalue": "",
            "status": "",
            "accumalated": "",
            "comment": ""
    }
}]

$("tr[data-id=1] > td:nth-child(1)").text(jsonPretty [0].main['tittle']);

$("tr[data-id=1] > td:nth-child(2)").text(jsonPretty [0].main['start value']);

$("tr[data-id=1] > td:nth-child(3)").text(jsonPretty [0].main['stop value']);

$("tr[data-id=1] > td:nth-child(4)").text(jsonPretty [0].main['status']);

$("tr[data-id=1] > td:nth-child(5)").text(jsonPretty [0].main['accumulated']);

$("tr[data-id=1] > td:nth-child(6)").text(jsonPretty [0].main['comment']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-id="1">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here it may help you out.

Comment: @ sachin GetPageInfoResult is not a variable for me my variable is jsonPretty

Comment: oh! you don't change my json string .i can't change it

Comment: didnt it help you out?